Powershell Foreach Get-ADGroupMember on Array of Group Names Not Returning Consistent Results
I am trying to get a list of all AD group members that are a part of at least one of four groups.
I placed the groups into an array and ran a foreach loop on it, piped into Get-ADUser -Filter * and filtered using Where-Object for disabled accounts.
It initially returns 11 results, though these accounts are not members of the groups in the array, and then all further results throw an error
Get-ADUser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.At line:1 char:50

CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (REDACTED) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException FullyQualifiedErrorId: InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

I had tried expanding the properties on Get-ADUser to no avail.
I tried specifying group directly instead of using the array and foreach loop, same error occurred.
These are the commands I ran:
$groups = @('Group1','Group2','Group3','Group4')

foreach ($i in $groups)  {Get-ADGroupMember $i | Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $False} | Select CN }

Also with the group specified directly without the array and foreach loop
Get-ADGroupMember 'Group1' | Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $False} | Select CN


Remove -Filter * from your examples. The objects are being piped, there is nothing to filter

The issue with your code is because you're using -Filter * when you're trying to pipe identities at the same time, simply remove that part from your code and it should work. You should also include a filter for members being of object class user otherwise Get-ADUser would throw errors when the piped identity isn't a user.
Get-ADGroupMember 'Group1' |
    Where-Object ObjectClass -EQ user |
    Get-ADUser -Properties CN |
    Where-Object Enabled -eq $False |
    Select-Object CN

A more efficient way to do it is to query AD for all users being a member of any of the groups in $groups, the code is a bit more complicated though.
$groups = @('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4')
$ldapFilter = -join @(
    '(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(|'
    $groups | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object { '(memberOf={0})' -f $_.DistinguishedName }
    '))'
)
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter -Properties CN | Select-Object CN

